# ¿Cómo imprimir datos especificos de una lista en c#?

Tags: c#, lista

Estoy trabajando con un programa que permita agregar datos como objetos en una Lista, en este caso el nombre y el apellido.

Lo que quiero lograr es que se muestren los de un nombre en específico, es decir, si introduzco 5 JUAN, 6 JAVIER y 3 JOSE me gustaría hacer una especie de consulta que solo me imprima de la lista los que se llamen JAVIER o algun que otro nombre en general.

Hasta ahora en el metodo **Mostrar()** más abajo en el código se puede observar que coloqué un bucle for que me imprima en base a la posición que se encuentren los datos, pero no he podido lograr aún que solo se impriman los que cumplan con un requisito en específico como mencioné anteriormente.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {

public string nombre;
public string apellido;
public static int posicion = 0;

//OBJETO
static MainClass empleado = new MainClass();

static List<MainClass> ListaEmpleados = new List<MainClass>();

public static void Main (string[] args) {

        Console.Write("INGRESE SU NOMBRE: ");
        empleado.nombre = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("INGRESE SU APELLIDO: ");
        empleado.apellido = Console.ReadLine();

        //INSERTA LOS DATOS EN LA LISTA
        ListaEmpleados.Insert(posicion, new MainClass
        {
            nombre = empleado.nombre,
            apellido = empleado.apellido

        });

        Console.Clear();
        Mostrar();
        posicion++;

        Main(new string[] { });
     }

        //METODO PARA MOSTRAR LOS DATOS
        public static void Mostrar(){

        for(int i = 0; i < ListaEmpleados.Count; i++){
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine($"[NOMBRE]: {ListaEmpleados[i].nombre} \n"+
        $"[APELLIDO]: {ListaEmpleados[i].apellido}");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

Haces una función que va a ser la responsable de devolver una lista con todos los empleados cuyo nombre sea igual al parámetro que le pasamos a la función.

¿Por qué usar una función?, pues porque podemos reutilizarla tantas veces como queramos sin duplicar código, lo cual mejora la legibilidad del código. En esta función empleamos **Linq**, por lo que debes agregar a los **usings** esto:

```
using System.Linq;

public static List<Empleado> Mostrar(string nombre)
{
   return listaEmpleados.Where(e => e.Nombre == nombre).ToList();
}
```

Si deseas no emplear **Linq** pues podrías hacer esto:

```
public static List<Empleado> Mostrar(string nombre)
{
   var lista = new List<Empleado>();
   
   foreach(var e in listaEmpleados)
   {
      if(e.Nombre == nombre)
      {
         lista.Add(e);
      }
   }

   return lista;
}
```

Aquí igualmente creamos una función y le pasamos como parámetro el nombre por el que queremos buscar. Dentro de la función declaramos una lista vacía del **tipo** **Empleado**, y recorremos mediante un **ciclo foreach** la lista original de todos los empleados. En cada iteración preguntamos si el nombre de ese empleado es igual al nombre que pasamos por parámetro, de ser iguales pues añadimos este empleado a lista. Cuando se termina el **ciclo foreach**, pues retornamos la lista creada en esta función.

En ambos casos puedes llamar a la función de esta forma:

```
var empleados = Mostrar(nombre); //Pasamos el nombre que nos interesa Juan, Javier, Pedro, etcétera.
```

Y para mostrar los datos de empleados sería:

```
foreach(var e in empleados)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Nombre: {0}, Apellidos: {1}", e.Nombre, e.Apellidos));  
}
```

Recorremos la lista y vamos mostrando el nombre y el apellido de cada elemento de la lista.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a realizar una consulta linq sobre una lista
Aquí te dejo algo mas de información.

https://sodocumentation.net/csharp/topic/68/linq-queries

```
      List<MainClass> nombres = new List<MainClass>();


    var shortTrees = nombres.Where(m => nombres.Nombre == "Juan");
```